# My computing teacher left me without an answer please help me internet

Tags: python

So I have this code

```
score = 0

def on_button_pressed_a():
    score = score + 1
    print(score)
input.on_button_pressed(Button.A, on_button_pressed_a)
```

And I know that the problem is the score = 0 being outside the subroutine.
However if I put score = 0 into the subroutine whenever the button is pressed it will always return to 0. How can i fix this (I cant use classes btw)

Comment: I am forced to be using microbit.org btw ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You return nothing??

Comment: (1) Write a title that describes the problem of the code, not your personal issues. (2) What happens, what should happen (edit the question to explain).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try putting `global score` at the start of `on_button_pressed_a`?

Comment: a return would work too no?

Comment: @JosipJuros This is not the important problem here.